# How to pass parameter containing spaces to Azure CLI command in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have a PowerShell script to run an Azure CLI command:

```
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string] $ruleName = "Trusted Device1"
)

az webapp config access-restriction add -g "my-rg" -n "my-app" --rule-name $ruleName --action Allow --ip-address "10.10.10.0/24" --priority 10;
```

It returns "Bad Request" because $ruleName contains space.

If I run the Azure CLI command directly from PowerShell command window with quoted string, it will work.

```
az webapp config access-restriction add -g "my-rg" -n "my-app" --rule-name "Trusted device1" --action Allow --ip-address "10.10.10.0/24" --priority 10;
```

So how do I quote string parameter containing spaces and pass it to Azure CLI command inside a PowerShell script?

Using the following in the script doesn't work

```
az webapp config access-restriction add -g "my-rg" -n "my-app" --rule-name "$ruleName" --action Allow --ip-address "10.10.10.0/24" --priority 10;
```

Comment: PowerShell automatically double-quotes variable values with spaces behind the scenes; try `$v='a b'; cmd /c echo $v`, for instance. (Conversely, even if you explicitly double-quote a value (`"$ruleName"`), PowerShell will pass the value _unquoted_ if it does _not_ contains spaces.) The commands posted in your question do not explain your symptom.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which environment or PowerShell version you are encountering this with, but I was able to run this successfully on `PowerShell 7.1` and `5.1` as well. With PS, wrapping the argument in quotation marks should suffice when passing an argument containing whitespace as follows:

```
.\CreateAccessRestriction.ps1 -ruleName "My Rule"
```

Also, to be sure of how the passed parameters are being interpreted, it should help to include `--debug` with the az cli command to test. This would print a debug log statement like:

```
DEBUG: cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['webapp', 'config', 'access-restriction', 'add', '-g', 'myRG', '-n', 'myApp', '--rule-name', 'My Rule', '--action', 'Allow', 
'--ip-address', '10.10.10.0/24', '--priority', '10', '--debug']
```

As mentioned in the Azure CLI docs, when working with Azure CLI commands, be aware of how your shell uses quotation marks and escapes characters. Due to a known issue in PowerShell, some extra escaping rules apply. This is described in detail in this article: [Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md).